# How to convert timestamp to yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss format in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

How to convert `26-Mar-15 03.42.43.601000000 pm` to `yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss`. Can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: Do you currently have a string, or an actual timestamp that is just being displayed like that by your client?

Comment: Thx anderi it's working as expected

Answer (score 2):

First convert your string/varchar2 into a timestamp, and then format it back to a string with your format:

```
SQL> select to_char
  2         ( to_timestamp('26-Mar-15 03.42.43.601000000 pm','dd-Mon-rr hh.mi.ss.ff9 am')
  3         , 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'
  4         )
  5    from dual
  6  /

TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAM
-------------------
2015-03-26 15:42:43

1 row selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo can convert the `date string` to `timestamp` by;

```
select to_timestamp('26-Mar-15 03.42.43.601000000 pm', 'dd-mon-yy hh.mi.ss.FF9 AM')
from DUAL
```

If you want to get the data in `yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss` then use `to_char` function

```
select 
    to_char(
        to_timestamp('26-Mar-15 03.42.43.601000000 pm', 'dd-mon-yy hh.mi.ss.FF9 AM'),
        'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'
    )
from DUAL
```